# Web Server to SQL Server Using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Does the server (Windows 2008 R2) running my ASP.net MVC application using Windows Authentication need to be setup for Delegation(within AD) in order for my Active Directory User ID & PW to be sent to a SQL Server that is on a different box.

Currently my server does not have delegation on.
When I run my app I am always getting login box when running code that connects to SQL Server. However this login always fail and at times crashed the application pool.

When I run the application locally from the server the application runs fine without the login box ever appearing.

Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0):

what about adding **aspnet** or **IIS** users to windows users of MS SQLServer? have you tried

Comment: Yes, the SQL Server has all my users that need access. When I run the app locally from the server everything works fine. When I run the app from any other machine I get a login box. If I enter my credentials, it fails and sometimes crashes the app pool